# unable to get init-parameter from servlet context using EL

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, el

I am trying to get value of `init parameter` defined in `web.xml` file. But I am getting `Http Status 500` exception.

code to get `init parameter` in JSP file:

```
init param: ${pageContext.servletContext.initParameter.mob}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>one/index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
<context-param>
<param-name>mob</param-name>
<param-value>nokia</param-value>
</context-param>
</web-app>
```

there is no problem when i try to get init parameter without EL using jsp syntax. But with EL its causing error. can anyone tell me how can i get this using EL

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @confile it was a problem of -> not able to get init param value from web.xml using EL in jsp.

Comment: Use EL expression to get init parameter from the servlet context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this expression.

```
${initParam['mob']}
```

Or maybe

`${pageContext.servletContext.initParameter['mob']}`